# First Responder not Changing

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview

Currently i have this tableview in my storyboard i have this structure in my table
[image]
[image]

i already have placed to each textfield a tag 0 - 6 and i have this piece of code

```
-(BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField{
    if(textField.returnKeyType == UIReturnKeyNext) {
        NSInteger nextTag = textField.tag + 1;
        UIResponder* nextResponder = [textField viewWithTag:nextTag];
        [nextResponder becomeFirstResponder];

    } else if (textField.returnKeyType == UIReturnKeyDone) {
        [textField resignFirstResponder];
    }
    return YES;
}
```

but for some reason it doesn't change to next textfield any ideas on what am i doing wrong?

Comment: are those cells are text fields ?

Comment: i just added the image of how is the table is structured @Mr.T

Comment: did u implement the delegate properly? How did you given the tag to textfields ?

Comment: yeah each uitextfield has it delegate and the tag i gave them through the attributes inspector @Mr.T

Comment: does this method textfieldshouldreturn get hit when you tap on textfield ?

Comment: yes it does and i goes inside through the if statement @Mr.T

Comment: why are you allocating the textfield to UIResponder ? Aren't you supposed to call [textfield resignFirstResponder] ?

Comment: well i was looking through some post i tried that one thats why i did it @Mr.T

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try resigning the old first responder first:

```
[textField resignFirstResponder];
[nextResponder becomeFirstResponder];
```

Sometimes it is a bit tricky, if this does not work you can try just if the [textField resignFirstResponder]; works... If it works and it is the [nextResponder becomeFirstResponder]; that does not work you can always try it with a delay: [nextResponder performSelector:@selector(becomeFirstResponder) afterDelay:0.1];

Hope it helps...

Comment: thanks man this helped! @Carles Estevadeordal but now im getting this 2 warnings
 _BSMachError: (os/kern) invalid capability (20)
 _BSMachError: (os/kern) invalid name (15)

Comment: I don't know man, I haven't ever seen those, I googled and it looks like a bug... XCode 7.1 is a "bit" buggy I think.

Answer (score 1):

According to [the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIView/viewWithTag:), the `viewWithTag:`'s return value is:

> **Return Value**
>
> The view in the receiver’s hierarchy whose tag property
>   matches the value in the tag parameter.

It seems unlikely that your `textField` is the parent view of some other text field.  You should probably call this on your table view or the view controller's `view` property.

Comment: so i should assign the tag to the table cell ? @Charles A.

Comment: No, the tag is assigned to the text field, but to get the text field (which is a UIResponder), you have to call viewWithTag: on a view that is above it (i.e., a parent to it) in the view hierarchy.